# Assigning a form input to a password field disallows user input

Tags: html, css, forms, input

So I am making a login form for a client and have come across a slight problem.
For some reason I cannot enter data into the password input.
I have no special css or anything on that specific input.
Here is what I currently have

```
<form>
    <li>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="input" name="username"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="input" name="password"/>
    </li>

    <li class="buttons">
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        <input class="button_end" id="button" type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </li>
</form>
```

This is my css:

```
li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Umm... Nop, not happening in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AAhuV/1/  You should have something else that is giving you that behavior.

Comment: There are some mistakes in the Form, as 2 input with same id, username has a password input type, and again you have 2 buttons with same id.

Comment: someone edited the form to that...i submitted a change to have it revert back

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the padding that was effecting input.. Not entirely sure why. But I removed the id's from the inputs so now it looks like this:

```
<form>
    <li>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </li>

    <li class="buttons">
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        <input class="button_end" id="button" type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </li>
</form>
```

Then the css

```
input {
width: 334px;
height: 32px;
background: #f6f6f6;
border: 1px solid #adadad;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: i bet you they're going to need the id....so add it to your css to override whatever css is there

Comment: What do I need an Id for?

Comment: lol....exactly...... na i bet they're using it for events or something javascript related. i'm not telling you 100%, but it sounds like you were handed something that you are not familiar with, and i would assume ids on a form are being used....thats all. so if you think thats your fix, and they come back and say we need ids, you are back to square one. just override the id, and you're good to go